# How to parse date in android format.

Tags: android, mobile

I have date in this formate 20141007T200000100000 i need to parse with time zone is UTC+10 but this   is vary with date see 100000 this is for UTC+10 so how to parse this date and store value in Date variable.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssSSSZ");
Date date = format.parse("20141007T200000100000");
Log.e("", "Share.datetime==" + date.toString());
```

Comment: seems you're nearly there, what's the problem?

Comment: have you check date is not parse ?

Comment: no I haven't, but if the date template is correct, and looks like it's decent, it should work. according to it, you have 2014-10-07 T 20h 00min 00sec 100decsec 000 ... how is the timezone encoded?? is it the last 3 digits?